# How to display a CSV list of data in a column of an RDLC file

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have a report embedded in a web application that works fine but I need to make a tweak to it.  Right now the report basically will dump all the rows from a view, I have some filters set up but I have disabled them to simplify this and get this working.  I spent all day yesterday trying to get this to work correctly, attempting many different combinations of things.  The end goals is to take a set of data and display it as a comma separated list within the same row that the data belongs to.

My data is a list of projects, each project can have multiple personnel associated with it, instead of having a new row for each person we want all the people in one column separated by commas that belong to the project.  A trivial task in SQL.

```
SELECT dbo.APM_Project.Code, dbo.APM_Project.Title, 

              (STUFF((SELECT(', ' + vi.NameFirst)
              FROM view_OrganizationPerson vi
              JOIN APM_Project as p ON vi.ProjectId = p.Id
              WHERE vi.ProjectId = APM_Project.Id
              AND vi.Role = 'Principal Investigator'
              AND vi.Status = 'Active'
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')) AS PI_


FROM         dbo.APM_Project
```

Also I have tried the SUBSTRING method of producing the comma separated list, **all of these methods work great when I run the SQL script, they also work when I preview the data from my dataset in visual studio** so something must be right.  I get the results I want however when I run the application, I get no data in the column using the expressions of

```
=Fields!PI_.Value
```

or

```
=First(Fields!PI_.Value, "DataSet1")
```

So I'm not entirely sure where to go from here.  This seems like it should be a pretty easy task, also when I run the expression

```
=Fields!PI_.IsMissing
```

it comes back true, so something is being lost at runtime and I just can't figure out what it could be.

All other data of the project is present within the text boxes, just the PI_ column is left blank.

Question is:**How do you display a CSV list of data in one column of a row of data in an RDLC file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is valid.  I needed to update the .aspx page with the changes made to the data adapter itself since I changed the data set.